# MySQL Query Optimization

Tags: mysql, database, optimization, query-optimization

I have the following query to select users and their locations, etc from MySQL (all InnoDB). The table `user`, `blocked_user` and `blocked_countries` have about 2mil rows each, `countries` about 250, `regions` about 3500 and `cities` about 2.8mil.

The Problem is that the query is quite fast (0.05sec) without `AND co.country_id='us'` in the `WHERE` clause. However, I tried around so much but just have the feeling that there must be certainly a much easier and better way for this query, no?

What am I missing? Any help is highly appreciated! Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: and how slow is it with the contry_id within the where clause?

Comment: @Sebas: I haven't figured out yet, as after some minutes I stopped the operation each time...

Comment: ok, one question: why are you using left joins? Do you know that by adding an equality in the where clause you transform a left join into an inner join? your statement about co.country_id = 'us' is affecting your left join with country table

Comment: anyway we'll need a real extract of the table structure I guess

Comment: @Sebas: really?? No, I did not know that! :O Oh, thank you very much for this, it explains a little bit now... OK, thank you I'll post the table structure.

Comment: yeah... i learnt it the hard way... LEFT JOIN means "bring me the records even if they don't match" and then, the where clause means "bring me the record that DO match with this". But to match your where clause they need to exist on the first place. This paradox therefore results into the exclusion of the null rows that would have been returned without the where clause.

Comment: The `AND NOT EXISTS` causes it to do a full table scan iirc, so it would have to hit every row.  In addition, you are doing `VARCHAR` comparisons instead of numeric types which is a lot slower.  `country_id` should be in `INTEGER`.  As Sebas said, the first two `LEFT JOIN`s are being nullified, so might as well remove them.  Range checks against the implicit conversion from `VARCHAR` -> `INTEGER` (my assumed data types) for the `birthdate` column will also be slow.

Comment: @judda: oh, thank you for those great tips! So, instead of `AND NOT EXISTS`is it better to do a `LEFT JOIN` `WHERE IS NULL`?

Comment: these 2 subqueries are totally independant, they should be executed before the main query I think. There is nothing to join with...

Comment: Yup that should be faster, as well the `WHERE` clause gets executed for each row in the result set, so they should should only be run once, you could do that through the `LEFT JOIN` as you said.

Comment: @judda: one question, though... how can I remove the first two `LEFT JOIN`s? I will then get the error "Unknown column"? So, I do need to specify the table somewhere, no?

Comment: I didn't mean remove them, I just meant replace them with `INNER JOIN`s.

Comment: @judda: ah, well I tried `INNER JOIN`s before, however they are slow (timeout). Do you have any idea why?

Comment: Are you missing indexes on the table?  `LEFT JOIN`s are by definition slower than `INNER JOIN`s so there may have been something else that is different?

Comment: @judda: hm, actually there are indexes and `EXPLAIN` says it is using `PRIMARY`... I could not think of anything else that changed. The question though is, what is exactly the join condition in `ON(...)`?

Comment: It is using the `PRIMARY KEY` indexes on their corresponding table, but you still need to index the column on the referencing tables (i.e. `country_id` on the city table)

Comment: @judda: yeah, there is an index on that field (I've posted the whole `INSERT` for both tables as an update). Furthermore I tried out the `LEFT JOIN` with `IS NULL` for the two queries checking the blocked user, it is in some cases much slower, especially if no blocked user is found, as it scans the whole table. You are right, that otherwise the `SELECT 1...` will be run each time, but in best case only 20 times (as the number of `LIMIT`), or until 20 matching rows are found, but not 2 million times...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you again for your help. Finally, I've found the direction where to solve the problem. The performance problem was mainly caused because of a mixture between a range scan and an `ORDER BY ... LIMIT`.

So, I've learned a lot (new to me) about indexing and found that if you have a range scan (as in my case age between x and y), then the ranging column must be the last in a concatenated index, otherwise the index cannot be used entirely. In addition, the column used to sort the results, must the last in the index. So, given a mixture between range scan and `ORDER BY`, you need to decide if the index should be used to sort or to select.

In my case it means thinking of some good combinations for several indexes, where the left over rows to be sorted are just a very few or if the search cannot be narrowed down to just some rows, a separate index that will be used for sorting as the query will then quickly find the number of rows as given by `LIMIT`.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the WHERE to HAVING for the country_id

```
AND birthdate <=  '802726152'
AND birthdate >=  '676495752'

ORDER BY u.id DESC
HAVING co.country_id='us'
LIMIT 20
```

Comment: The `HAVING` clause is for comparing values which were being aggregated in some sort of way, not adding in additional filtering.

Comment: I trust that you've tested this before downvoting my post? I would suggest doing so. MySQL's website would confirm the following "The WHERE clause is used to restrict records, and is also used by the
query optimizer to determine which indexes and tables to use.  HAVING
is a "filter" on the final resultset, and is applied after ORDER BY and
GROUP BY, so mysql cannot use it to optimize the query." The reason why I didn't need it to optimize the query, is because OP said it was already running fast without the country, so by using HAVING after the fact, he maintains his speed

Comment: @BryanMoyles: thank you Bryan for your help. Indeed, it was faster with using `HAVING`, probably because MySQL would not use `country_id` as a key, as you mentioned... it still takes some seconds, though.. but thank you again! :)

Comment: You're very welcome, I'm glad that it helped solve your problem :) Would you consider accepting my answer if it did indeed solve the problem to the best that it could be solved for the time being?

Comment: Hi Bryan, well to be honest it did not really help solving the problem. For that query it was faster, however still took between 6 and 45sec, which still is not acceptable for requesting data for 20 users on a search page as you have to admit... so I am still left alone with what I can improve. I managed to change the LEFT JOINS to INNER JOINS as judda suggested in his comments, so things slowly start to speed up. I appreciated your help, though...